# Websockets with Rails(Puma) - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-4.1, puma, websocket-rails

I am trying to use websocket in my Rails4.1 application

Here are some relevant code snippets:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'websocket-rails'
gem 'puma'
```

development.rb

```
 config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock
```

I am starting the server locally as:

```
bundle exec puma -p 3000
```

In the chrome console I see a connection error:

```
new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/post/hello', true);

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/post/hello' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Can anyone help with what I need to do to use web sockets locally in Rails?

---

**Update1**

I tried adding following as per [Websockets not working in my Rails app when I run on Unicorn server, but works on a Thin server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657405/websockets-not-working-in-my-rails-app-when-i-run-on-unicorn-server-but-works-o) but it did not help

initializers/eventmachine.rb

```
Thread.new { EventMachine.run } unless EventMachine.reactor_running? && EventMachine.reactor_thread.alive
```

Comment: reason for downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I would advise against removing 'Rack::Lock' unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your console:

```
window.dispatcher = new WebSocketRails window.document.location.host + '/websocket'
```

You configure the rest of what you want to do in the **config/events.rb** file and whatever controllers you use to handle the events

Comment: This. The Websocket-Rails gem is [hardcoded to use the '/websocket' route](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/blob/master/lib/rails/config/routes.rb).